# Architecture of C++ matrix classes: inheritance or specialisation?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, architecture, template-specialization

I would like to define a class :
`template <class T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N> class Matrix`
with simple and classic methods applied to any matrix (`std::array<std::array<T, N>, M> m_data;`).

I then want to have specialised classes such as: `template <class T> class Matrix<T, 2, 2>`. Ideally I want to be able to use the generic methods of the first class in the specific class. To do this I was thinking of creating a template `class <class T> class Matrix2x2 : public Matrix<T, 2, 2>` to have heritage. The problem is that to use for example the method `class Matrix<T, M, N>::transpose()` from `Matrix2x2` I have to cast the value returned in `Matrix2x2`, something I'd rather avoid.
`Matrix2x2<T> and Matrix<T, 2, 2>` are completely equivalent in practice, so using class specialisation seems appropriate, but then you have to rewrite all the methods and either duplicate some code or create an instance of the non-specialised class and I want some specific methods for specific dimension (e.g. rotation) in each corresponding method.

I've tried using inheritance, it works but I have a lot of code duplication, I'd like to refactor all the code.
What's the best design? Is there a better solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show us the code. Also https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why is 2x2 a special case anyway? I understand when people specialize `vec<2>` to have `x`,`y` as member names, but why a matrix? If you just want some custom functions, don't specialize anything and use `requires` to conditionally enable the functions.

Comment: Ignoring that, having a separate `class Matrix2x2` sounds like a bad idea, because some people/code will use it, and some will use `Matrix<T,2,2>`, causing inconsistency. Instead, inherit `Matrix` and all its specializations from a CRTP base class, and move everything there. (When compilers implement C++23 explicit `this` parameter, you'll be able to use that in your base class instead of CRTP.) CRTP solves the issue with the return type of `transpose()`, for example.

Comment: Instead of transpose (and moving data around in memory) you can also create a view (iterators) on your matrix that visits all your memory locations (as long as the pattern is predictable caching will still work). Have a look at [std::mdspan].  I would certainly not create specialized versions based on matrix size (unless you have a proven performance issue), and code reuse is about the worst reason to look at inheritance. Though there is the CRTP/mixin approach where you pull in a templated specialization class with implementaion (might also be worth looking into)

Comment: [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) solves this with the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I want to define 2x2 3x3 4x4 matrix as specific cases because for now I don't want to define determinant and inverse for other dimensions. i also want to give rotation/transformation methods to those dimensions.

Comment: Determinant and inverse can be free functions defined for each of those those three specific cases. No need for them to be member functions.

Comment: @PepijnKramer CRTP/mixin approach seems promising. I've never used this design, I'm still struggling to establish the precise architecture of my Matrix classes: I'd have a class MatrixBase<X, T, M, N> and classes: class Matrix2x2 : public MatrixBase<Matrix2x2<T>, T, 2, 2>, ... ? but what about matrices of any dimension?

Comment: @Julienchz You don't really need any specializations, just plop all functions in one class, and write `requires` conditions for them.

Comment: If you want to continue with CRTP, you wouldn't have a °Matrix2x2` class anymore. `Matrix` would inherit from `MatrixBase`, and all specializations of `Matrix` would also inherit.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I should only have two classes: a MatrixBase class and a Matrix class and use requires to specialise certain matrix dimensions? Why use CRTP with a single inherited class?

Comment: @Julienchz No, those are two alternative solutions. 1 - Just a single `class Matrix`, no specializations, no inheritance, all functions in once place with `requires` to only enable them for certain dimensions. 2 - `class Matrix` and its specializations inherit from `MatrixBase` using CRTP. *"Why use CRTP with a single inherited class?"* Specializations would inherit too, so you can reuse code across specializations.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've started refactoring my code with CRTP but I'm going to have a problem with the multiplication of MxN and NxN1 matrices, my derived class must be different for the two input matrices and for the output matrix.

Comment: @Julienchz I suggest asking a new question about that. I don't understand what the issue is without the code. Also I'd probably use `requires` instead of CRTP; CRTP is more useful when you have some member variables only in some specializations, or when you strictly need more than one class/specialization and neither applies in your case.